# Why does this print 1, 0, 0 instead of 1, 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def fancy_divide(numbers, index):
    try:
        denom = numbers[index]
        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            numbers[i] /= denom
    except IndexError:
        fancy_divide(numbers, len(numbers) - 1)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("-2")
    else:
        print("1")
    finally:
        print("0")

fancy_divide([0, 2, 4], 4)
```

I expect the output to be `1, 0` but the actual output is `1, 0, 0`.

Comment: Both the initial call and the recursive call have a `finally`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

def is called twice, so finally is called twice and output is 1 0 0.
so, if you want your output as 1 0, you can write code as below,

```
    def fancy_divide(numbers, index):
    try:
        denom = numbers[index]
        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            numbers[i] /= denom
    except IndexError:
        try:
            fancy_divide(numbers, len(numbers) - 1)
        finally:
            print("0")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("-2")
    else:
        print("1")


fancy_divide([0, 2, 4], 9)
```

but I think, writing below will be correct way of doing it,

```
def fancy_divide(numbers, index):
    try:
        denom = numbers[index]
        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            numbers[i] /= denom
    except IndexError:
        try:
            fancy_divide(numbers, len(numbers) - 1)
        finally:
            print("0")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("-2")
    else:
        print("1")
    finally:
        print("0")

fancy_divide([0, 2, 4], 9)
```

but here output will be 1 0 0 0.